# React Native for Windows app on Tab Navigator show Rectangle icons in React Navigation 6.1.9

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-vector-icons, react-native-windows

I'm trying to use icon (Ionicons by Ionic) in my project (**React Native for Windows app**) from https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons and it work very well in android but in Desktop app is show Rectangle. I did to add font files (...\TestNavigation1\windows\TestNavigation1\Assets\Ionicons.ttf). Despite all this, the icons still won't display. What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional steps I need to take to get the icons to show up? Thank you.

**Image:**
[Android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnSsn.jpg)
[Desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfDmN.png)

**On set BottomTabNavigator**

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { ROUTES } from '../constants';
import { HomeScreen, WalletScreen, NotificationsScreen, SettingsScreen } from '../screens';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
                    let iconName;
                    if (route.name === ROUTES.HOME_TAB) {
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
                    } else if (route.name === ROUTES.SETTINGS) {
                        iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline';
                    } else if (route.name === ROUTES.WALLET) {
                        iconName = focused ? 'wallet' : 'wallet-outline';
                    } else if (route.name === ROUTES.NOTIFICATIONS) {
                        iconName = focused ? 'notifications' : 'notifications-outline';
                    }
                    return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                },
            })}
            >

            <Tab.Screen name={ROUTES.HOME_TAB} component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name={ROUTES.WALLET} component={WalletScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name={ROUTES.NOTIFICATIONS} component={NotificationsScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name={ROUTES.SETTINGS} component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>

    )
}

export default BottomTabNavigator
```

**On Home page**

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {COLORS} from '../../constants';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: COLORS.bgColor,
      }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text> 
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color='#e91e63' size={20} />

    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

I need Desktop app is show icons same android app

Answer (score 1):

You have added wrong font, so Window app cannot display as you wish.

You use `MaterialCommunityIcons`, so you need to add `MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf` to `assets` folder, not `Ionicons.ttf`

Comment: I've done so far.  Add three font files ( Ionicons.ttf, MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf, FontAwesome.ttf) to assets folder.

Comment: @OrrOPrm. Did you follow all step in this doc: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#windows-via-react-native-windows ?

Comment: I'm not sure, Did I do it right? because in VS code I copy and paste the font files to assets folder and in Microsoft visual studio I follow the doc but 'recompile project' is meaning rebuild? if it mean rebuild I did it (Rebuild in Microsoft visual studio)

Comment: How to recompile react native in Terminal?